# Change only one value and keep other intact Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

A lot of answered question about how to change a single value, but I still can't figure it out how to change only `type` value only for Mac and keep other values intact.

```
const initialStateMac = {
    type: MacBook,
    os: MacOS
};

const initialStatePc = {
    type: Laptop,
    os: Windows
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    mac: macReducers,
    pc: pcReducers
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export const Mac = (state = initialStateMac, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_DEVICE_TYPE":
            return {
                ...state,
                type: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const Pc = (state = initialStatePc, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_DEVICE_TYPE":
            return {
                ...state,
                type: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

{
    type: "SET_DEVICE_TYPE",
    payload: "ddd"
}
```

to be clear, I want get:

```
    Mac: {
        type: ddd,
        os: MacOS
    },
    Pc: {
        type: Laptop,
        os: Windows
    }
```

but not:

```
    Mac: {
        type: ddd,
        os: MacOS
    },
    Pc: {
        type: ddd,
        os: Windows
    }
```

Comment: you're using react-redux?

Comment: @Taylor Burke yes

Comment: I would say go with Davit's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case with multiple reducers just using different action types for every reducer correspondingly would be the easiest solution

*The answer below was given with the assumption that 1 reducer was used with initalState `{Mac: {type: "", os: ""}, PC: {type: "", os:""}}`*

If you want to specifically change type attribute of the object with "Mac" key You could use this.

```
export default (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_DEVICE_TYPE":
            const {Mac} = state;
            return {
                ...state,
                Mac: {
                   ...Mac,
                   type: action.payload
                }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Note: If you want to specifically change type attribute of the object with "Mac" key, then would be better if the action type was like `"SET_MAC_DEVICE_TYPE"`

Also if the key need to be dynamic -

```
// action.payload = {key: "Mac", type: "ddd"}

export default (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_DEVICE_TYPE":
            const initValue = state[action.payload.key];
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.key]: {
                   ...initValue,
                   type: action.payload.type
                }
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: I updated the question, I get "undefined" for const {Mac} = state; in your original answer. I forget to mention that I use combineReducers, would you mind to take a look one more time?

Comment: Quote: `In case with multiple reducers just using different action types for every reducer correspondingly would be the easiest solution`, it doesn't solve the problem. If I have `type:` key in several objects. This is what I tried to show in my current approach

Answer (score 0):

Pass initialState.Mac into the reducer as the default state

```
export default (state = initialState.Mac, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_DEVICE_TYPE":
            return {
                ...state,
                type: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```